# How to receive standard out in python program

Tags: python

Long story short, I am writing python code that occasionally causes an underlying module to spit out complaints in the terminal that I want my code to respond to. My question is if there is some way that I can take in all terminal outputs as a string while the program is running so that I might parse it and execute some handler code. Its not errors that crash the program entirely and not a situation where I can simply do a try catch. Thanks for any help!

Edit: Running on Linux

Comment: Windows, Linux, Mac, Solaris, OpenBSD?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout?

Comment: The module you're using should return results to you, the caller, rather than print anything to stdout/stderr so you don't have to capture and parse.

Comment: Have you checked whether the underlying module uses `logging` ? https://pymotw.com/3/logging/index.html

Comment: What "underlying module"?  It could be using the warnings module.

Answer (score 0):

there are several solutions to your need. the easiest would be to use a shared buffer of sort and get all your package output there instead of `stdout` (with regular `print`) thus keeping your personal streams under your package control.

since you probably already have some code with `print` or you want for it to work with minimal change, i suggest use the `contextlib.redirect_stdout` with a context manager.
give it a shared `io.StringIO` instance and wrap all your method with it.
you can even create a decorator to do it automatically.

something like:

```py
// decorator
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io
import functools

SHARED_BUFFER = io.StringIO()

def std_redirecter(func):
  @functools.wrap(func)
  def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    with redirect_stdout(SHARED_BUFFER) as buffer:
      print('foo')
      print('bar')
      func(*args, **kwargs)

  return inner

// your files
@std_redirecter
def writing_to_stdout_func():
  print('baz')

// invocation
writing_to_stdout_func()

string = SHARED_BUFFER.getvalue() // 'foo\nbar\nbaz\n'
```